# SVAR Impulse responses out of confidence interval

Tags: montecarlo, confidence-interval

I computed impulse responses of a SVAR model with 4 variables using VAR package. the IRF for one of the variable stays out of the confidence band for 4 quarters. What can explain this? and how can it be fixed? I know bootstrap is used to compute the CI, is there any alternative way like monte carlo simulation that can be used in VAR package?

sirf1_2 = irf(SVAR1, impulse = "Ugap", response = c("TFP","Ugap","RCFG","RDG"), n.ahead=50, runs = 200, ci=0.68)

Comment: could you specify language/tools?